# Processing large amounts of XML with Pika and XMLSchema

Tags: python, xml, rabbitmq, pika

Currently I am ingesting data from a rabbitMQ queue. The format is XML, I have a callback that will parse and then write that data to a database. However, when this is deployed, its timing the consumer out. I have it running on a batch insert, so we are waiting for the RabbitMQ queue to have at least a 1000 records, and then receiving them. My callback then iterates through the records and parses them.

that parser looks something like this

```
from xmlschema import XMLSchema
xml = XMLSchema("standard.xsd")
def parse(raw_xml, batched_data):
    if xml.is_valid(raw_xml):
        batched_data.append(xml.decode(raw_xml))
```

not all the logic but I am able to deduce this is where I am timing out. Any suggestions on how I can resolve this bottle neck? I may very well not be using this library correctly so please let me know.

For the record: we receive about 100 records per second so lowering this batch is not plausible.
Thanks in advance

Comment: How long before timeout?

Comment: @jdweng fairly certain its 60 seconds

Comment: When you run can you check in Task Manger the amount of memory being used?  How large is the Xml File.  What library are you using for parse?  Need to find out if Parse or Append is the bottleneck.